# Converting to homogenuous coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves, homogeneous-spaces

Let's assume elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{R}$:

$y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$

How to convert this equation to homogeneous coordinates?

My notes say it's $zy^2=x^3+xz^2+z^3$. Unfortunately, I have no idea where that came from and whether it's correct or not.

Comment: That's correct. You just add the $z's$ so that the equation is homogeneous. (of degree 3)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Is there a 'formula' to do that?

Comment: Just what (the other) John said. Basically, the whole equation needs to be homogeneous and you want the given equation to be the restriction to $z\neq 0$, for which we can set $z=1$. So just supply enough factors of $z$ to bring every term up to the degree of the highest-degree term; on the set $z=1$ you then get back the equation you started with.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't just "add $z$'s" until the equation is homogeneous, and no, you don't substitute $z=1$, as the comments above may suggest. This works, but that's not the reason, and not what is formally happening.

Let's work backwards. Let's start with a curve given in projective coordinates, let's say
$$C: f(X,Y,Z)=ZY^2 - X^3 - XZ^2-Z^3=0,$$
i.e., 
$$C=\{[x_0,y_0,z_0]\in\mathbb{P}^2 : f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0\}.$$
There is a map from $C$ to an "affine patch" $E$ of $C$ given by such that
$$\phi([X,Y,Z]) = (X/Z,Y/Z)$$
which is well-defined for all points on $E$ with $Z\neq 0$. In other words, $\phi:C\setminus\{[0,1,0]\} \to E$. This is called de-homogenizing the equation of $C$ (note that there are other affine patches we could take). We also note that if $f(X,Y,Z)=0$, and $Z\neq 0$, then dividing through by $Z^3$ we obtain
$$\frac{Y^2}{Z^2} - \frac{X^3}{Z^3} -\frac{X}{Z}-1=0$$
or, in other words, $(X/Z,Y/Z)$ satisfy the equation $y^2=x^3+x+1$, so the affine patch $E$ is the curve defined by this affine equation.

Conversely, if we begin with an affine patch of a curve $E:y^2=x^3+x+1$ we find the projective model by inverting $\phi$, i.e., set
$$C: (Y/Z)^2 =(X/Z)^3+(X/Z)+1,$$
and multiply through by $Z^3$ to obtain
$$C : ZY^2 = X^3 +XZ^2+Z^3.$$

In general, the homogeneous equation of a curve $E:f(x,y)=0$, where the highest degree of a monomial of $f$ is $d$, is given by $$C:Z^df(X/Z,Y/Z)=0.$$